# How to form nested json from sql parent child relation table

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

My sql procedure gives the below output.
[image]

If you look into the table id 1,2,5 and 6 has childs 0r 2,3,6,7 has parents. Corresponding parent id is given in parentid column.

Now in C#.Net I have to convert this table into nested json. That is child element inside parent element like below.

[image]

How to do it. Please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create an object that has properties corresponding to the properties in your table, then serialize it into JSON.

If I had to take a stab at what those classes would be, probably something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public PersonAttributes attributes {get; set;}
    public List<Person> Children {get; set;}
}

public class PersonAttributes
{
    public bool HasChild {get; set;}
    public bool HasParent {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
}
```

Then you could code your constructor to take the DataTable to sort out and assign the data as you need.

For the serialization, I recommend [JSON.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), I use it all the time and it has never failed me.

Comment: Hi chriszumberge, thanks for your comment. It gave me the basic idea of how to implement it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This should help get you started at least, but you'll need SQL Server 2012. You didn't specify the version you're using.

```
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(50), value varchar(50), HasParent varchar(3), ParentID int, HasChild varchar(3))
insert into @t
exec dbo.YourStoredProc

select
      id
    , name
    , value
    , HasChild 'attributes.HasChild'
    , HasParent 'attributes.HasParent'
    , ParentID  'attributes.ParentId'
    , child.id  'children.id'
    , child.name 'children.name'
    , child.value 'children.value'
    , child.haschild 'children.attributes.haschild'
    , child.hasparent 'children.attributes.hasparent'
    , child.parentid 'children.attributes.parentid'
    , gchild.id 'children.children.id'
    , gchild.name 'children.children.name'
    , gchild.value 'children.children.value'
    , gchild.haschild 'children.children.attributes.haschild'
    , gchild.hasparent 'children.children.attributes.hasparent'
    , gchild.parentid 'children.children.attributes.parentid'
from @t t
join @t child on child.ParentID = t.id
join @t gchild on gchild.ParentID = child.id
for json auto
```

Comment: Thanks.I was using sql server 2008 version when i posted this question.

Comment: Correction, FOR JSON wasn't added to SQL Server until 2016.